# Finding Record Type IDs

Tags: data-loader

Export a report on the Contract Record Type ID's. I want the name and Record type ID's (18 digit long ID's) of the Contract record types who's name starts with "BUNDLE".

Comment: Appu, it doesn't appear as you've done a lot of research before asking and I'd encourage you to do so. You can query the RecordType object using SOQL to achieve what you're after.

Comment: Agreed with LaceySnr .This can be easily researched and let us know if you still did not get any hint

Comment: You can start here : https://eu1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/reports_overview.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done with reports, however, you can achieve this by using the Dataloader and exporting to CSV, you can then open the csv in Excel, Open Office or something else.

1. Start up the dataloader
2. Log in
3. Export
4. Check "Show all salesforce objects" at the top
5. Click on RecordType in the list
6. At choose target for extraction: you pick a directory on your hard drive where the CSV must be stored. Click NEXT
7. In the next window, at the bottom, in the box saying "the generated query will appear below. You may edit it before finishing" you fill in:

   SELECT Name, Id, DeveloperName, SobjectType 
   FROM RecordType
   WHERE SobjectType = 'Contract'
   AND DeveloperName LIKE 'BUNDLE%'
8. Click Finish
9. If a message box appears, click YES
10. Now go to the directory you picked in step 6, and there you'll find your export.

Good luck!

Comment: Alternatively use workbench.developerforce.com and user query in step 7. Choose to export results as a csv

Comment: Thanq thanq,,,its work

Comment: Your problem is fixed now? If so, please upvote my answer and mark it as correct please :)